# PHP - Simple Subtraction Doesn't Add Up

Tags: php

I have no idea why this simple mathematical equation doesn't work. It's making me crazy - am I blind? Instead of subtracting `$number` from `$Amount2` it produces a negative number. So if `$Amount2` starts with a value of **100** and `$number` is a value of **10** I get **-10** instead of **90** as the result.

```
//find how much green they are holding
 $resultto = db_query("SELECT * FROM Users_Panickles WHERE PSID ='$PSID'");
$rowgifter = db_fetch_array($resultgifter);//fetch the name of the giftee character
$Amount2 = $resultgifter["Amount"];

//now alter the accounts
$Amount2 = $Amount2 - $number; //subtract the gift from the gifter's account and update the record
db_query ("UPDATE Users_Panickles SET Amount='$Amount2' WHERE PSID = '$PSID'");
```

Comment: Should be `$rowgifter = db_fetch_array($resultto);` and `$Amount2 = $rowgifter"Amount"];` after. What/where do you assign something to `$resultgifter` variable at all?

Comment: I achieve the correct result when setting the values for $Amount2 and $number manually to the values you provided. It should be inside the logic of your code.

Comment: Are you making sure that `$resultgifter["Amount"]` is actually returning a positive value?